# Is SQL Compact 4 suitable for a multi user ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: sql, linq

I'm considering using SQL Compact 4 for my ASP.NET Web Application, the program will be used internally at a corporate customer. The database will be populated with my customers supplier database (full SQL, approx 10,000 records) every X hours, the contents can then be searched via a web browser by multiple people at once, probably not more than 20. I have to deliver a web app that can be easily installed on a server where there is no full version of SQL and I can't talk to the supplier database directly as it is very slow (WAN link, firewalls etc).

Would SQL Compact 4 be a good choice? I would like to use LINQ.

Thanks
James

Comment: I would say a careful yes. As SQL Server Compact 4.0 has been designed to work under web load, max 256 concurrent connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief: no.

SQL Server Compact is designed to be a stand-alone, one-user data store - typically on disconnected / only occasionally connected clients, for instance mobile devices.

If you have a company, several concurrent users and such a scenario - use a server-based solution. SQL Server Express is free to use and quite capable, otherwise go with the full SQL Server product.

You'll need to find an efficient way to load / distribute your supplier's data somehow - but I would investigate various options under the assumption your server that your clients will run against does have a SQL Server version installed.